# JMS setTimeToLive

Tags: oracle, jms

I'm using JMS topic to publish messages. And on the message producer I'm setting setTimeToLive.I'm expecting the messages to be deleted after 16 hours. But even after 16 hours the message is still there in DB as well as in topic. Any thoughts on this? Am i missing something?

```
private static final long DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE = 16 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
....
session = getSession(jndiContext);
MessageProducer mp = createTopicMessageProducer(session, jndiContext, topicName);
mp.setTimeToLive(DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE);
Message msg = session.createObjectMessage(obj);
....
```

my oracele-jdbc2-service.xml have following queries

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.mq.pm.jdbc2.PersistenceManager"
  name="jboss.mq:service=JDBCPersistenceManager">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="ConnectionManager">jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=OracleDS</depends>
    <attribute name="SqlProperties">
      INSERT_EMPTY_BLOB = INSERT INTO JMS_MESSAGES (MESSAGEID, DESTINATION, MESSAGEBLOB, TXID, TXOP) VALUES(?,?,EMPTY_BLOB(),?,?)
      LOCK_EMPTY_BLOB = SELECT MESSAGEID, MESSAGEBLOB FROM JMS_MESSAGES WHERE MESSAGEID = ? AND DESTINATION = ? FOR UPDATE
      BLOB_TYPE=BINARYSTREAM_BLOB
      INSERT_TX = INSERT INTO JMS_TRANSACTIONS (TXID) values(?)
      INSERT_MESSAGE = INSERT INTO JMS_MESSAGES (MESSAGEID, DESTINATION, MESSAGEBLOB, TXID, TXOP) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
      SELECT_ALL_UNCOMMITED_TXS = SELECT TXID FROM JMS_TRANSACTIONS
      SELECT_MAX_TX = SELECT MAX(TXID) FROM (SELECT MAX(TXID) AS TXID FROM JMS_TRANSACTIONS UNION SELECT MAX(TXID) AS TXID FROM JMS_MESSAGES)
      DELETE_ALL_TX = DELETE FROM JMS_TRANSACTIONS
      SELECT_MESSAGES_IN_DEST = SELECT MESSAGEID, MESSAGEBLOB FROM JMS_MESSAGES WHERE DESTINATION=?
      SELECT_MESSAGE_KEYS_IN_DEST = SELECT MESSAGEID FROM JMS_MESSAGES WHERE DESTINATION=?
      SELECT_MESSAGE = SELECT MESSAGEID, MESSAGEBLOB FROM JMS_MESSAGES WHERE MESSAGEID=? AND DESTINATION=?
      MARK_MESSAGE = UPDATE JMS_MESSAGES SET TXID=?, TXOP=? WHERE MESSAGEID=? AND DESTINATION=?
      UPDATE_MESSAGE = UPDATE JMS_MESSAGES SET MESSAGEBLOB=? WHERE MESSAGEID=? AND DESTINATION=?
      UPDATE_MARKED_MESSAGES = UPDATE JMS_MESSAGES SET TXID=?, TXOP=? WHERE TXOP=?
      UPDATE_MARKED_MESSAGES_WITH_TX = UPDATE JMS_MESSAGES SET TXID=?, TXOP=? WHERE TXOP=? AND TXID=?
      DELETE_MARKED_MESSAGES_WITH_TX = DELETE FROM JMS_MESSAGES MESS WHERE TXOP=? AND EXISTS (SELECT TXID FROM JMS_TRANSACTIONS TX WHERE TX.TXID = MESS.TXID)
      DELETE_TX = DELETE FROM JMS_TRANSACTIONS WHERE TXID = ?
      DELETE_MARKED_MESSAGES = DELETE FROM JMS_MESSAGES WHERE TXID=? AND TXOP=?
      DELETE_TEMPORARY_MESSAGES = DELETE FROM JMS_MESSAGES WHERE TXOP='T'
      DELETE_MESSAGE = DELETE FROM JMS_MESSAGES WHERE MESSAGEID=? AND DESTINATION=?
      CREATE_MESSAGE_TABLE = CREATE TABLE JMS_MESSAGES ( MESSAGEID INTEGER NOT NULL, \
         DESTINATION VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, TXID INTEGER, TXOP CHAR(1), \
         MESSAGEBLOB BLOB, PRIMARY KEY (MESSAGEID, DESTINATION) )
      CREATE_IDX_MESSAGE_TXOP_TXID = CREATE INDEX JMS_MESSAGES_TXOP_TXID ON JMS_MESSAGES (TXOP, TXID)
      CREATE_IDX_MESSAGE_DESTINATION = CREATE INDEX JMS_MESSAGES_DESTINATION ON JMS_MESSAGES (DESTINATION)
      CREATE_TX_TABLE = CREATE TABLE JMS_TRANSACTIONS ( TXID INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (TXID) )
      CREATE_TABLES_ON_STARTUP = TRUE
    </attribute>
    <!-- Uncomment to override the transaction timeout for recovery per queue/subscription, in seconds -->
    <!--attribute name="RecoveryTimeout">0</attribute-->
    <!-- The number of blobs to load at once during message recovery -->
    <attribute name="RecoverMessagesChunk">0</attribute>
  </mbean>
```

Answer (score 2):

The JMS specification does not require the provider to ever delete the message.  Some providers delete expired messages rather quickly.  Some do not delete them until a browse or get operation evaluates the message for expiry.  Some will arbitrarily delete messages every so often regardless of whether a client has attempted to browse or get them.  Keeping a background task alive to delete expired messages quickly obviously consumes resources so most providers will opt for some degree of "lazy" expiration.

Interestingly, the JMS specification also states that "clients should not receive messages that have expired; however, JMS does not guarantee that this will not happen."  Most providers do a good job of preventing expired messages from being delivered but this is not a hard requirement.

So the answer is that although seeing the message in the DB or on a queue/topic after expiry may not be intuitive as the "expected" behavior, it is within the spec.  The more important question is whether said message is delivered to your application or not.  Hopefully it is not - but even if it is, the spec does not rule this out.

Answer (score 0):

Your Publisher/Subscriber should be coded in such a way to discard the expired messages as per the JMS specification. There is no guareente that the message is removed from the queue after it expires.

Answer (score 0):

Hi TTL also depends on configuration of application of Application Server, If you are using Jboss 6 then its internally using HornetQ for JMS, Hence some configuration are needed in standalone-full.xml for TTL to be working effectively.

message-expiry-scan-period, max-delivery-attempts that need to be configured in order to make TTL working.